# Why No Source and Destination IPs in UDP Datagram?

Tags: udp, layer4

In literature, I see UDP [datagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram) format as following:
[image]

I cannot understand why it does not include source and destination IP addresses?

Comment: Hmmm, no mac-address shown either.

Comment: What is the difference between a segment and a packet?

Comment: A packet contains IP source and destination, a segment contains protocol information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you're looking at the *UDP Datagram*, which is the payload in an *IP Datagram*.  The *IP Header* has the src/dst IP addresses.

Comment: Why are we having the source and destination ports in UDP Datagram in that case?

Answer (score 2):

At transmission the psuedoheader is added for the destination and source IP addresses. [This](http://medusa.sdsu.edu/network/CS576/Lectures/ch11_UDP.pdf) might clarify the process a bit more:

By itself, the UDP packet header only contains the source port and destination port of the client/target as well as a checksum and length.

This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359045/what-is-the-significance-of-pseudo-header-used-in-udp-tcp) asked on StackOverflow:

Comment: The pseudoheader is only used for calculating checksums, it is never actually transmitted.